Nuances entre "se griser" et "se saouler" ?
J'ai consulté le TLFi pour comprendre les nuances entre se griser et se saouler.
Pour griser, il est dit :

"Faire boire quelqu'un de manière à le rendre plus ou moins ivre.
Synon. enivrer, saoûler. Elles s'amusèrent à le griser avec le madère
de l'illustre Worms (Zola, Curée,1872, p. 412)." et "[En parlant des
vins, de l'alcool, etc.] Porter à la tête, enivrer."

Quant à saouler, le TLFi mentionne :

"B. − Cour., fam. [Le compl. désigne une pers.] 1. [Le suj. désigne
une boisson alcoolisée] Rendre ivre, porter à la tête. Synon. enivrer,
griser. Quelques verres l'ont soûlé. [Le compl. désigne un animal]
Raisin de choix qui peu à peu se ride (...) se musque et saoule les
oiseaux (Colette, Jumelle, 1938, p. 7). 2. [Le suj. désigne une pers.]
a) [Avec une valeur factitive] Faire trop boire, rendre ivre. Synon.
enivrer, griser. Tu me diras pas à moi qui t'ont pas saoulé pour te
faire signer (Roy, Bonheur occas., 1945, p. 65). b) Le plus souvent en
empl. pronom. réfl. Boire avec excès."

Ma question est donc la suivante : est-ce que la différence entre se griser et se saouler se résume à une question d'excès ?

Je vais relire L'assommoir pour voir quel mot il utilise.

Se griser est désuet. La seule forme qu'on rencontre encore assez souvent est l'adjectif grisant (C'est grisant) avec lequel on ne fait plus tellement de rapprochement avec l'alcool.
Se saouler (généralement orthographié soûler voire souler suivant les recommandations de 1990) est ce qu'on utilise le plus souvent pour dire qu'on boit et atteint l'état d'ébriété. Attention, soûlant a une toute autre signification: très ennuyeux.
Une forme plus soutenue est s'enivrer et à l'inverse, se bourrer est le synonyme le plus familier.
S'il fallait définir une gradation, je dirais que se bourrer est le plus intense de ces verbes.
Il existe quantité d'autres synonymes argotiques, tels que se biturer, se cuiter, se murger, se beurrer, se péter la gueule, se poivrer, se pinter, etc.

Et se biturer?

@Frank Oui, je l'ajoute avec quelques autres.

@LPH Oui, déjà là.
